# Fill columns of a matrix with sin/cos without for loop

Tags: python, numpy

Whenever I write a for loop I ask myself if there wouldn't be a more functional way to write it. I'm failing at coming up with something for this for loop, filling up columns of a matrix with sin/cos.

```
k = 5 #this is any odd integer
t = np.arange(0,N)/fs #time array for the sin/cos

A = np.zeros((N,k))
A[:,0] = 1
for i in range(1, k, 2):
    A[:,i] = np.cos(2*np.pi*freq*t*(i+1)/2)
    A[:,i+1] = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t*(i+1)/2)
```

I'm using numpy as this is used for more math afterwards. I realize there probably isn't any benefits in replacing the for loop as it's pretty trivial, but is there a way to replace this for loop?

Comment: in python you can use some functional programming paradigms. But it is not primarily a functional programming language. Rewriting numpy code in a functional way rarely makes any sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of NumPy's vectorization to, rather than a loop, use an indexing array, e.g.:

```
assert k & 1
odd = np.arange(1, k, 2)
even = odd + 1
A = np.zeros((N, k))
A[:, 0] = 1
A[:, odd] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * freq * t[:, None] * even / 2)
A[:, even] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t[:, None] * even / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tile and build out `A` with the values you use in your loop.  Then you can just use that matrix and try to do the cos and sin calculations all at once:

```
A = np.tile(np.arange(0, 5), (3,1))
A[:,0] = 1
A[:,1:] += 1
```

A then looks like this:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Then you can vectorize the calculation maybe?

```
cos = np.cos(2*np.pi*freq*t*(A)/2)
sin = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t*(A)/2)
```

But you will still have to put it back into the orignal matrix. You could take even strides as a mask and use fill A with the cos.  Then take odd strides as mask and fill with sin.

Not sure if that helps (or if correct), just another way to think without using the loop.